# A lemma regarding polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I was doing a math olympiad problem when I chanced upon this lemma in the solution. The solution used it without proof, but I do not understand why this is true.

If $A\neq B$, and $P$ is a polynomial, then $A-B\hspace{1mm}|\hspace{1mm}P(A)-P(B)$.

I have tried by writing $P(x)=a_ix^i+a_{i-1}x^{i-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$.

$$P(A)=a_iA^i+a_{i-1}A^{i-1}+...+a_1A+a_0$$
$$P(B)=a_iB^i+a_{i-1}B^{i-1}+...+a_1B+a_0$$
$$P(A)-P(B)=\left(a_iA^i+a_{i-1}A^{i-1}+...+a_1A+a_0\right)-\left(a_iB^i+a_{i-1}B^{i-1}+...+a_1B+a_0\right)=a_i\left(A^i-B^i\right)+a_{i-1}\left(A^{i-1}-B^{i-1}\right)+...+a_1\left(A-B\right)$$
However, this does not seem to help. Could someone give me a proof of this fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lemma is correct if $A,B$ are integers and $P(x)$ has integer coefficients.  Note that

$$A^k-B^k=(A-B)(A^{k-1}+A^{k-2}B + \cdots + AB^{k-2}+B^{k-1}).$$

Therefore $A^k-B^k$ is a multiple of $A-B$.

Now suppose you have any polynomial $P(x)=a_n x^n + \dots + a_0$.  Then

$$P(A)-P(B) = a_n(A^n-B^n) + a_{n-1}(A^{n-1}-B^{n-1}) + \dots + a_1(A-B),$$

and each term in parenthesis is (by the above remarks) a multiple of $A-B$.  If you add up a bunch of terms, each of which is a multiple of $A-B$, the sum will also be a multiple of $A-B$.  Therefore, $P(A)-P(B)$ is a multiple of $A-B$.